# How do I take the results of multiple selects and combine into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that contains information for 4 electrical generators. I would like to have the results of the four querys in one row. Does any one have a suggestion?

```
SELECT  avg(KW) as GEN_101_AVG
FROM         genset WHERE     (GenSetName   like 'GEA3519') and GenDate >= '1 jan   2003    00:00:00' and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'

   SELECT  avg(KW) as GEN_201_AVG
FROM         genset WHERE     (GenSetName   like 'GEA3520') and GenDate >= '1 jan 2003 00:00:00' and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'

SELECT  avg(KW) as GEN_301_AVG
FROM         genset WHERE     (GenSetName   like 'GEA3521') and GenDate >= '1 jan 2003 00:00:00' and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'

SELECT  avg(KW) as GEN_401_AVG
FROM         genset WHERE     (GenSetName   like 'GEA3522') and GenDate >= '1 jan 2003 00:00:00' and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Please use the 'sqlserver' tag rather than 'mssql'. Watch the suggestions when tagging your questions: any tag with a number less than 10 after it's name is probably wrong. In this case, there are over 5000 questions tagged 'sqlserver' and ZERO tagged 'msssql'.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  avg(KW)
        FROM    genset
        WHERE   (GenSetName   like 'GEA3519')
                and GenDate >= '1 jan   2003    00:00:00'
                and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
        ) AS avg_GEA3519,
        (
        SELECT  avg(KW)
        FROM    genset
        WHERE   (GenSetName   like 'GEA3520')
                and GenDate >= '1 jan   2003    00:00:00'
                and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
        ) AS avg_GEA3520,
        (
        SELECT  avg(KW)
        FROM    genset
        WHERE   (GenSetName   like 'GEA3521')
                and GenDate >= '1 jan   2003    00:00:00'
                and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
        ) AS avg_GEA3521,
        (
        SELECT  avg(KW)
        FROM    genset
        WHERE   (GenSetName   like 'GEA3522')
                and GenDate >= '1 jan   2003    00:00:00'
                and GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
        ) AS avg_GEA3522
```

, or in `SQL Server 2005+`, this:

```
SELECT  [GEA3519], [GEA3520], [GEA3521], [GEA3522]
FROM    (
        SELECT  GenSetName, KW
        FROM    genset
        WHERE   GenDate >= '1 Jan 2003  00:00:00'
                AND GenDate < '1 Feb 2003 00:00:00'
        ) AS q
PIVOT
(
        AVG(KW)
        FOR  GenSetName IN (['GEA3519'], ['GEA3520'], ['GEA3521'], ['GEA3522']
)
```

Comment: My thoughts entirely- though I would personally alias those columns too.

Comment: Well, that's good too :-) I was a little late posting my variable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
SELECT
     AVG(GEN_101.kw) AS GEN_101_AVG,
     AVG(GEN_201.kw) AS GEN_201_AVG,
     AVG(GEN_301.kw) AS GEN_301_AVG,
     AVG(GEN_401.kw) AS GEN_401_AVG
FROM
     Genset GEN_101
INNER JOIN Genset GEN_201 ON
     GEN_201.GenSetName = 'GEA3520' AND
     GEN_201.GenDate >= '1 jan 2003 00:00:00' AND
     GEN_201.GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
INNER JOIN Genset GEN_101 ON
     GEN_301.GenSetName = 'GEA3521' AND
     GEN_301.GenDate >= '1 jan 2003 00:00:00' AND
     GEN_301.GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
INNER JOIN Genset GEN_101 ON
     GEN_401.GenSetName = 'GEA3522' AND
     GEN_401.GenDate >= '1 jan 2003 00:00:00' AND
     GEN_401.GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
WHERE
     GEN_101.GenSetName = 'GEA3519' AND
     GEN_101.GenDate >= '1 jan 2003 00:00:00' AND
     GEN_101.GenDate < '1 feb 2003 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This will indeed work for AVG (and only for AVG), since AVG does not depend on how many times the table is being cross-joined to another table. Performance will of course be poor, but a working and not so obvious solution deserves a +1.

Answer (score 1):

As the number of selects is limited to four, one solution would be to select into variables and then do a final select. Like the following:

```
declare @var1 <TYPE>
declare @var2 <TYPE>
declare @var3 <TYPE>
declare @var4 <TYPE>

select @var1 = SELECT avg(...) ...
select @var2 = ...
select @var3 = ...
select @var4 = ...

select @var1 as ..., @var2 as ..., @var3 as ..., @var4 as ...
```

Comment: you might better go with the above subquery solution. You may use my approach in case you need to manipulate the four values before selecting.